# What UN policies could help end the Rohingya crisis?

Tags: united-nations, myanmar

We all are aware of the condition of Rohingya, a Muslim minority, in Myanmar.

No country is giving them shelter, though some are living in Bangladesh and India. Still, they have to find a permanent solution for themselves. If they remain in the condition they are living right now then I am sure that some of them will go to war.

What are the UN policies for this kind of matter, what feasible, permanent and safe solution is there for them?

Comment: The Universal Declaration of Human Rights has something to say on the subject. "All are equal before the law and are entitled without any discrimination to equal protection of the law." and "Everyone has the right to recognition everywhere as a person before the law."

Answer (score 5):

It's [not true](https://worldview.stratfor.com/article/tangled-web-myanmars-rohingya-crisis) that no country is giving them shelters.

[image]

The real problem is inside Burma. There is [ethnic cleansing](http://www.latimes.com/world/asia/la-fg-india-rohingya-20170918-story.html) going on. The situation is almost identical to the Bosnian War where [Bosnians faced ethnic cleansing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srebrenica_massacre) by Serbs and Croats.

So, sending peacekeeping forces would be the right solution.